# Removing previously added objects from mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I want to delete the previously added objects, except 5 recently added objects from a collection in mongodb based on Date.

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any context, I can only give a simple example on *mycollection* which has a timestamp attribute *ts*:

```
var lastkeeplist = db.getCollection('mycollection').find({}).sort({"ts" :-1}).skip(4).limit(1)
var lastkeep = lastkeeplist[0]
//db.getCollection('mycollection').find({ "ts" : { "$lt" : lastkeep.ts }})
db.getCollection('mycollection').remove({ "ts" : { "$lt" : lastkeep.ts }})
```

This assume there is always at least 5 documents.